# Can't reach apache server with ssl through haproxy

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, haproxy

In my network i have a DNS server, a HAProxy server and 2 webservers.
When i try to go through the haproxy (getting the domain IP from the DNS server) it gives me a different error then when i go without it.

I don't care much about http connection w/ haproxy just ssl so fixing that isn't a priority.
When i do the next curl commands without haproxy (writing server ip in /etc/hosts) i get:

```
$ curl http://www.catsfood.com
<h1>www.catsfood.com</h1>
<h1>IP is: 10.0.0.14</h1>
```

```
$ curl https://www.catsfood.com -lv
*   Trying 10.0.0.14:443...
* Connected to www.catsfood.com (10.0.0.14) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
*  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
```

Through HAProxy server:

```
$ curl https://www.catsfood.com -lv
*   Trying 10.0.0.17:443...
* Connected to www.catsfood.com (10.0.0.17) port 443 (#0)
...
*  subjectAltName: host "www.catsfood.com" matched cert's "www.catsfood.com"
*  issuer: C=IL; ST=Tel-Aviv; L=TLV; O=Ben Ltd; OU=Ben Ltd; CN=www.ben.com; m
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.catsfood.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.76.1
> Accept: */*
> 
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS alert, close notify (256):
* Empty reply from server
* Closing connection 0
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, close notify (256):
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

```
$ curl http://www.catsfood.com -lv
*   Trying 10.0.0.17:80...
* Connected to www.catsfood.com (10.0.0.17) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.catsfood.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.76.1
> Accept: */*
> 
* Empty reply from server
* Closing connection 0
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

The httpd.conf file is the same as the default one but added Listen 443
haproxy.cfg:

```
frontend web_frontend
  bind *:80
  bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.pem
  mode tcp
  option tcplog
  default_backend web1
  acl ACL_bighead.com hdr(host) -i www.bighead.com
  acl ACL_bighead.com hdr(host) -i bighead.com
  use_backend web2 if ACL_bighead.com

backend web1
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    option tcp-check
    server web01 10.0.0.14:443 check ssl verify none

backend web2
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    option tcp-check
    server web02 10.0.0.15:443 check ssl verify none
```

**ssl.conf**

```
<VirtualHost www.bighead.com:443>
ServerAdmin webmaster@ssl-tutorials.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ServerName www.bighead.com:443
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_log
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key
SSLUseStapling off
</VirtualHost>



SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH
SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder On

Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains"
Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY
Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff

SSLCompression off
SSLUseStapling on
SSLStaplingCache "shmcb:logs/stapling-cache(150000)"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't put domain names in the `<VirtualHost>` tag. That's not what the field is for. If you want to match against the HTTP 'Host:' header (or against the TLS SNI), use `ServerName` and `ServerAlias`.

The `<VirtualHost>` tag takes a *local IP address* that'll be matched against whatever local address received the HTTP connection on the web server. This feature is used for IP-based virtual hosts (where each vhost has a dedicated IP address); *not* for name-based virtual hosts.

So for example, if the domain `www.bighead.com` points at the HAproxy server, then your Apache config works as if you actually specified `<VirtualHost 10.0.0.17:443>`, and that isn't going to match *any* connection to the web server (whose address is still 10.0.0.14!).

The OpenSSL error message "ssl3_get_record:wrong version number" usually indicates that it has received something that isn't a SSL/TLS packet at all – e.g. the server might have sent a plaintext HTTP response. (You could use tcpdump to find out.)

Why would the server send a plaintext HTTP response on a HTTPS port? Probably because the connection *didn't match* any virtual host that would have `SSLEngine On` – which is probably because you put the wrong addresses in all of your VirtualHost tags.

Generally, all your plain HTTP vhosts should use `<VirtualHost *:80>` and all your HTTPS virtual hosts should use `<VirtualHost *:443>` unless you have a specific need to do otherwise.

Comment: Omg you are amazing!
Ty very much :D
The problem was indeed the virtual host tag, changed it on the server to * and it indeed worked! Ty very much :D